# Compile VS project with Typescript in node

Tags: typescript

We have always used the Typescript VS 2013/2015 extensions and they work great.

But since 1.5 they changed it so it always compiles the complete project instead of just the file you saved.

With a few 100 files this is unworkable, slowdowns and compile times of up to 2 minutes.

Somebody suggested to use NodeJS with tscw to watch for changes.

But what command line parameters do I give to compile a complete VS project, I searched through the documentation but it's very unclear.